# Parse JSON key that is either object or array of object

Tags: java, json, moshi

In Moshi, is it possible to create a type adapter that would parse both an object or a list of objects of the same type?

For example, sometimes the JSON is:

```
{
  "person": {...}
}
```

Other times it is:

```
{
  "person": [{...}, {...}]
}
```

Ideally, I'd want to have a Java object looking like this:

```
class PersonContainer {
  @PersonsList List<Person> persons; // @List(Person.class) would be even better
}
```

Comment: You can mark the field as `Object` and create a getter to check if the type is a collection of not.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you make just what you said, an adapter. 
make a function(the adapter) to check whether its a single object or an array, probably based on the '[' char and the adapter will direct the input into the right handling function.

another method is to assume all the input is arrays and work from there.