# Moshi: Parse single object or list of objects (kotlin)

Tags: android, json, kotlin, adapter, moshi

### Problem

How to parse either a single `Warning` object or a list of `Warning` objects (`List<Warning>`) from an API using [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi)?

The response as a single warning:

```
{
  "warnings": {...}
}
```

The response as a list of warnings:

```
{
  "warnings": [{...}, {...}]
}
```

##### Trial and Error

Tried to shoehorn an autogenerated [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) adapter. Tried to build on top of it but failed.

### Solution

##### Generalized approach with a factory

I tried to translate the adapter Eric wrote from Java to Kotlin since I realized that a more general approach is better much like Eric points out in his reply.

Once it works, I will revise this post to make it easier to understand. A bit messy now I'm sorry.

**EDIT**: I ended up using the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49204281/2352843) Eric suggested in another thread (translated into Kotlin).

##### Adapter with factory

```kt
package org.domain.name

import com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonQualifier
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonReader
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonWriter
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi
import com.squareup.moshi.Types
import java.util.Collections
import java.lang.reflect.Type
import kotlin.annotation.AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME
import kotlin.annotation.AnnotationTarget.FIELD

class SingleToArrayAdapter(
    val delegateAdapter: JsonAdapter<List<Any>>,
    val elementAdapter: JsonAdapter<Any>
) : JsonAdapter<Any>() {

    companion object {
        val factory = SingleToArrayAdapterFactory()
    }

    override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): Any? =
        if (reader.peek() != JsonReader.Token.BEGIN_ARRAY) {
            Collections.singletonList(elementAdapter.fromJson(reader))
        } else delegateAdapter.fromJson(reader)

    override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: Any?) =
        throw UnsupportedOperationException("SingleToArrayAdapter is only used to deserialize objects")

    class SingleToArrayAdapterFactory : JsonAdapter.Factory {
        override fun create(type: Type, annotations: Set<Annotation>, moshi: Moshi): JsonAdapter<Any>? {
            val delegateAnnotations = Types.nextAnnotations(annotations, SingleToArray::class.java) ?: return null
            if (Types.getRawType(type) !== List::class.java) throw IllegalArgumentException("Only List can be annotated with @SingleToArray. Found: $type")
            val elementType = Types.collectionElementType(type, List::class.java)
            val delegateAdapter: JsonAdapter<List<Any>> = moshi.adapter(type, delegateAnnotations)
            val elementAdapter: JsonAdapter<Any> = moshi.adapter(elementType)
            return SingleToArrayAdapter(delegateAdapter, elementAdapter)
        }
    }
}
```

##### Qualifier

Note: I had to add the `@Target(FIELD)`.

```kt
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(FIELD)
@JsonQualifier
annotation class SingleToArray
```

##### Usage

Annotate a field you want to make sure is parsed as a list with `@SingleToArray`.

```kt
data class Alert(
    @SingleToArray
    @Json(name = "alert")
    val alert: List<Warning>
)
```

and add the adapter factory to your [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) instance:

```kt
val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(SingleToArrayAdapter.factory)
    .build()
```

### Reference

- [Parse JSON key that is either object or array of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110184/parse-json-key-that-is-either-object-or-array-of-object)
- [Moshi Determine if JSON is array or single object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49165604/moshi-determine-if-json-is-array-or-single-object/49201415#49201415)
- https://github.com/square/moshi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the API returns either 1 object if there is only 1 or > 1 a list of objects.

Create an adapter that peeks to see if you're getting an array first.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49165604/moshi-determine-if-json-is-array-or-single-object/49204281#49204281) is exactly what you want. It includes a qualifier, so you can apply it only to lists that may have this behavior for single items. `@SingleToArray List<Warning>`.

There is another example of dealing with multiple formats [here](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/recipes/MultipleFormats.java) for further reading.

Comment: Eric, thank you for your reply -- the links you posted is indeed what I am looking for and I did end up with something "like that", however it feels like im still missing something. I have updated my answer with current adapter code im using, it works but it feels dirty.. what do you think?

Comment: Use a JsonAdapter.Factory, and you won't need to pass in the Moshi instance.

Comment: I have tried to use a Factory to avoid the moshi instance but somehow that completely changed the behaivor of the adapter but I think I am close, im probably just missing something trivial. I added the code for reference meanwhile.

Comment: I did get it to work eventually, forgot to clean the project inbetween builds. I thank you and have also accepted your answer since it was what I eventually ended up using :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Another Solution

Based on Eric Cochran's [Java version solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49204281/1850858).

```kt
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter.Factory
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonQualifier
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonReader
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonReader.Token.BEGIN_ARRAY
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonWriter
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi
import com.squareup.moshi.Types
import java.lang.reflect.Type
import java.util.Collections.singletonList
import java.util.Collections.emptyList
import kotlin.annotation.AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME
import kotlin.annotation.AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(PROPERTY)
@JsonQualifier
annotation class SingleOrList

object SingleOrListAdapterFactory : Factory {
    override fun create(
        type: Type,
        annotations: Set<Annotation>,
        moshi: Moshi
    ): JsonAdapter<*>? {
        val delegateAnnotations = Types.nextAnnotations(annotations, SingleOrList::class.java)
            ?: return null
        if (Types.getRawType(type) !== List::class.java) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("@SingleOrList requires the type to be List. Found this type: $type")
        }
        val elementType = Types.collectionElementType(type, List::class.java)
        val delegateAdapter: JsonAdapter<List<Any?>?> = moshi.adapter(type, delegateAnnotations)
        val singleElementAdapter: JsonAdapter<Any?> = moshi.adapter(elementType)
        return object : JsonAdapter<List<Any?>?>() {
            override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): List<Any?>? =
                if (reader.peek() !== BEGIN_ARRAY)
                    singletonList(singleElementAdapter.fromJson(reader))
                else
                    delegateAdapter.fromJson(reader)
            override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: List<Any?>?) {
                if (value == null) return
                if (value.size == 1)
                    singleElementAdapter.toJson(writer, value[0])
                else
                    delegateAdapter.toJson(writer, value)
            }
        }
    }
}

class TheUnitTest {

    @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    internal data class MockModel(
        @SingleOrList
        val thekey: List<String>
    )

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun testAdapter() {
        val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(SingleOrListAdapterFactory).build()
        val adapter: JsonAdapter<List<String>> = moshi.adapter(
            Types.newParameterizedType(
                List::class.java,
                String::class.java),
            SingleOrList::class.java
        )
        assertEquals(adapter.fromJson("[\"Alice\",\"Bob\"]"), listOf("Alice", "Bob"))
        assertEquals(adapter.toJson(listOf("Bob", "Alice")), "[\"Bob\",\"Alice\"]")

        assertEquals(adapter.fromJson("\"Alice\""), singletonList("Alice"))
        assertEquals(adapter.toJson(singletonList("Alice")), "\"Alice\"")

        assertEquals(adapter.fromJson("[]"), emptyList<String>())
        assertEquals(adapter.toJson(emptyList()), "[]")
    }

    @Test
    fun testDataClassUsage() {
        val j1 = """
            {
                "thekey": "value1"
            }
        """.trimIndent()
        val j2 = """
            {
                "thekey": [
                    "value1",
                    "value2",
                    "value3"
                ]
            }
        """.trimIndent()

        val o1 = MockModel::class.java.fromJson(j1, moshi)?.thekey
        val o2 = MockModel::class.java.fromJson(j2, moshi)?.thekey

        if (o1 != null && o2 != null) {
            assertEquals(o1.size, 1)
            assertEquals(o1[0], "value1")
            assertEquals(o2.size, 3)
            assertEquals(o2[0], "value1")
            assertEquals(o2[1], "value2")
            assertEquals(o2[2], "value3")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked exactly as I expected, but can you please help me understand the role of `delegateAnnotations`, `elementType`, `deletegateAdapter`, `singleElementAdapter` and how are they derived. Thanks @George